# Redirecting the output directory of 'mvn package' or 'mvn compile' command

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, resin

I am working on a Java project (where maven is the build tool) with resin server. I found some nice `plugins` for Tomcat  by which if I issue a `'mvn compile'` then the compiled file goes to the `<tomcat>/webapps` directory. But I have not found any `plugin` for resin to do the same task. So now I am trying to change the output directory for `'mvn compile'` or `'mvn package'` command. Can anyone suggest me how can I do this?

By default the output of `mvn compile` or `mvn package` goes to the `<project_dir>/target`. But I want to place the output to '~/resin_hosts' directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the following property in the POM:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${user.home}/resin_hosts</outputDirectory>
</build>
```

The [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) also allows changing the directory of the jar:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
       ...
       <outputDirectory>output_dir</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```